# Azure Data Storage: Unable to upload file (Not authorized to perform this operation using this permission)

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm trying to follow the example to upload a file to Azure Data Storage as mentioned in the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=visual-studio%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli%2Cidentity-visual-studio

Following is my code:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Azure.Identity;

// TODO: Replace <storage-account-name> with your actual storage account name
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
        new Uri("https://[some azure storage]"),
        new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Set container name
string containerName = "data";

// Get container
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

// Create a local file in the ./data/ directory for uploading and downloading
string localPath = "data";
Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath);
string fileName = "testupload" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);

// Write text to the file
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFilePath, "Hello, World!");

// Get a reference to a blob
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobClient.Uri);

// Upload data from the local file
await blobClient.UploadAsync(localFilePath, true);
```

But I'm getting an error message that the request is not authorized.

Error message:

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
```

I have Contributor role (which based on description is Grant full access to manage all resources ....), is this role still not enough to perform the operation?

[image]

Comment: You would need “Blob Storage Data Contributor” role to upload blobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

*Initially I tried same code in my environment and got same error*

**Console:**

[image]

> Azure.RequestFailedException: 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

The above error occurs when your principal doesn't has access to azure blob storage.

For accessing blob storage through identity, *Gaurav Mantri* comment it is correct, you need a role to access blob storage,
The roles are

- Storage-blob-contributor(or)
- Storage-blob-owner

Go to portal -> storage accounts -> Access Control (IAM) ->Add -> Add role assignments -> storage-blob-contributor or storage-blob-owner role to the storage account.

**Portal:**

[image]

*After assigning role to my storage account, I executed same code and it successfully uploaded file in azure blob storage.*

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Azure.Identity;

// TODO: Replace <storage-account-name> with your actual storage account name
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
        new Uri("https://[some azure storage]"),
        new DefaultAzureCredential());

// Set container name
string containerName = "test";

// Get container
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

// Create a local file in the ./data/ directory for uploading and downloading
string localPath = "data";
Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath);
string fileName = "testupload" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);

// Write text to the file
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFilePath, "Hello, World!");

// Get a reference to a blob
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobClient.Uri);

// Upload data from the local file
await blobClient.UploadAsync(localFilePath, true);
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Comment: `For accessing blob storage through identity, Gaurav Mantri comment it is correct, you need a role to access blob storage, The roles are` not 100%. The given code uses oauth tokens for storage account data layer access and therefore those roles are needed. But is is possible to use `BlobServiceClient` with `StorageSharedKeyCredential ` and then `Contributor` RBAC is enough for fetching storage account keys.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have to change the Network Access to **[Enable Public to All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyUiE.jpg)**, if you're not using VPN or dedicated Network to access Azure Environment.